# How can I view the raw Visualforce of an existing (out of the box) page?

Tags: visualforce, account

I want to override the Accounts page, but retain the existing version as a template upon which to make changes. Is there any way to view or clone the existing code for the Account page?

Answer (score 2):

The "out of the box" appearance of the Account page is driven by layouts - WYSIWG arrangements of fields and related data - that are listed under Setup -> Customize -> Accounts -> Page Layouts. You can edit those layouts or create new ones and assign them via the "Page Layout Assignment" button. So there isn't any Visualforce markup to start from.

Moving to Visualforce is a big change to how the page is rendered, with the definition changing to a collection of nested tag elements. This ultimately does give you more control over what the page can do, but unless done carefully can be jarring for users if most of the other pages remain layout based. And it takes effort.

There are posts like this [Generate a Visualforce Page from an Existing Page Layout](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/02/09/generate-a-visualforce-page-from-an-existing-page-layout/); I presume there are more recent tools available too. (The layout files - XML definitions of sections and fields - are available via an API and tools can be written to transform those.)

The Visualforce is hooked in via Setup -> Customize -> Accounts -> Buttons Links & Actions. So you can flip backwards and forwards between the layout-based pages and the Visualforce one through these settings.

If your org is used for multiple applications, you need to make sure that your Visualforce page supports the needs of all the applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is an AppExchange package called EasyPage (it's private, but available) that will let you generate Visualforce to mimic a layout, including all fields and labels. You may wish to update it to include describe field label values for localization, etc.

http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016kP8EAI